# Where clause not working for Alphanumeric values

Tags: sql, sql-server, nhibernate

I have a problem, getting wrong result when user enter criteria for some rows but result is wrong. The main problem is to find if 'AV99' is bigger or 'AV102' in where clause.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Section
(
       Section varchar(50) NULL
)
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV01')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV02')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV03')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV04')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV05')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV06')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV07')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV08')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV09')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV10')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV11')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV12')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV13')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV14')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV15')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV16')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV17')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV95')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV96')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV97')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV98')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV99')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV100')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV101')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV201')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV202')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV301')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV401')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AV501')

SELECT Section,
       LEFT(Section,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section)-1),
       CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(Section,PATINDEX('[0-9]%',Section),LEN(Section)))
FROM dbo.Section
Where  Section between 'AV09' and 'AV99'
ORDER BY LEFT(Section,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section)-1), -- alphabetical sort
         CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(Section,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section),LEN(Section))) -- numerical sort
```

The result I am getting is this

```
AV09    AV  9
AV10    AV  10
AV11    AV  11
AV12    AV  12
AV13    AV  13
AV14    AV  14
AV15    AV  15
AV16    AV  16
AV17    AV  17
AV95    AV  95
AV96    AV  96
AV97    AV  97
AV98    AV  98
AV99    AV  99
AV100   AV  100
AV101   AV  101
AV201   AV  201
AV202   AV  202
AV301   AV  301
AV401   AV  401
AV501   AV  501
```

But it should be

```
AV09    AV  9
AV10    AV  10
AV11    AV  11
AV12    AV  12
AV13    AV  13
AV14    AV  14
AV15    AV  15
AV16    AV  16
AV17    AV  17
AV95    AV  95
AV96    AV  96
AV97    AV  97
AV98    AV  98
AV99    AV  99
```

I am doing it for NHibernate but if there is any easy solution in SQL then please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: You need to do the same trick as in order by.

Comment: its not just order by, I checked sorting is working but where is not working

Comment: You have to extract the integer before comparing...

Comment: The code is alphanumeric so dont know position of number and characters.

Comment: Does SQL Server have any collations with numeric sorting?

Comment: I also tried this on sorting but did not work, SELECT Section
FROM dbo.Section ORDER BY Section COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN ASC

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
WHERE Section between 'AV09' and 'AV99'
```

Because values such as `AV100` are *alphabetically* between those.  You can use the same code you have in the `ORDER BY` like this:

```
WHERE CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(Section,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section),LEN(Section))) 
    BETWEEN 9 AND 99
```

Comment: How do you know the number in the code. It could be anything as its a alphanumeric. It could be a combination like 'A0B01', '00210', 'ABBAAS' etc.